# Trying to find name of book written before 2000 where society can genetically modify themselves

Tags: story-identification, books, genetic-engineering, virus

Trying to find name of book where a scientist created a virus that would allow people to rapidly change themselves genetically, including adding animal features, become blonde, musclemen, etc. The main character is a "normal" detective trying to stop a bomb being set off by mafia (which leaders had turned themselves to sharks). He fails and bomb goes off in the city. Bad guys thought it would force everyone to change but in reality the scientist who developed virus regretted it and set off a permenant antidote to force humanity back to being fully human.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, take a look at [*Armed Memory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312857667) by James (or Jim) Young. Published in 1995, Tim Wandel wants to be a journalist but ends up working for his cousin, Johnny Stevens, who specializes in biotech and designer genes in a place called Microde City. The bad guys are the Hammerheads.

Found by searching, "science fiction" human shark genetic. A forum post at sffchronicles.com mentioned it although that OP was looking for "head implants and sharks in space".

[image: cover of Armed Memory by Jim Young]